# Should I use duplicate data or a reference-key?

Tags: database-design, duplicates, key, nuxt.js

I'm making a nuxt web-app with which a user can create invoices. I will use firestore as the database, with 2 main folders/collections: clients & invoices

The user can add clients consisting of a client-id and some more client-info. Also, the user can create invoices containing this client-info among other things.

In the database, should I store this client info in the invoice itself or should I just store the client-key as a reference to the client-info?
Storing it inside the invoice itseld will lead to duplicate data, but may simplify developing as I don't need to loop and find the right client every time I need some client-info.

Comment: This is unfortunately opinion-based and should be clsoed.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the client-info inside your invoice, but copy only the necessary data (you don't need the client dog name in your invoice, probably).

It is not exactly a duplicate, because you want to know what was the info at the time you created the invoice. You don't want your past invoices changing every time a client-info is updated.

Comment: ofcourse, didn’t think about it that way. Thanks!